# Exercises and solutions for natural deduction proofs in Robinson and Peano arithmetic

Tags: logic, reference-request, axioms, peano-axioms, natural-deduction

Does any of you know where I can find Exercises and solutions for natural deduction proofs in Robinson and Peano arithmetic?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](http://www.logicinaction.org/docs/ch9.pdf) some exercises for formal proofs in Peano arithmetic using natural deduction.

Consider that in general proofs in natural deduction of basic properties of Peano arithmetic such as commutativity of multiplication may be very long and tedious.

Comment: Alternatively, we can use an algebraic axiomatization of PA, such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations), so that one can go on to more interesting theorems such as $\forall p,q ( p·p = q·q+q·q ⇒ p = 0 )$. =)